# Cannot install arch linux on acer predator Helios neo 16

Tags: arch-linux, archiving, dualboot, issue-tracking, acer

I'm trying to install arch linux on acer predator Helios neo 16 but the issue is that when i boot into the arch live environment for further installation it gets stuck in mounting process while copying the rootfs [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYAWk.jpg) [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKrb1.jpg) to Ram ,I did turn off the secure boot , vda , and fast startup. Something after a few reboot it opens the archiso prompt but it automatically generated few code after a period of nearly 5 seconds
[Img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw6Cq.jpg)

Comment: can you edit your question to include the error message(s) as text please

Comment: What you describe has nothing to do with what you disabled. Arch works with Secure Boot since more than a decade ago and the other are irrelevant. Redo your live/installation media because it most likely has to do with a bad "burn" or other corruption.